# How do I go back to playing the main game after having started the Epilogue/Origin?

Tags: splice

There's a couple of Angelics that I left for later but now I can't go back to try to perfect them.

Answer (score 3):

The "Origin" is the main game. The "Epilogue" is additional levels beyond the 'normal' levels--beyond the credits rolling. You can switch between Origin and Epilogue by tapping/clicking the word Origin or Epilogue as shown below.

**Epilogue with a 'link' to Origin**
[image: Epilogue to Origin]

**Origin with a 'link' to Epilogue**
[image: Origin to Epilogue]